# How to create a duplicate of a stack in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, stack

My teacher requested that I create a duplicate of a Stack that returns a new Stack containing the same elements and in the same order as the specified Stack.

If I am only able to use methods that are unique to Stack, I would pop every element off the Stack and onto a que. Then I would pop from the bottom of the que onto a new Stack and return the new Stack.

However, I figured that since Stack inherits from Vector I could just use the addAll() method from Vector!

Here is the Java code implementation:

```
public class DuplicateStack {

private Stack backStack;

public Stack duplicateStack(Stack s) {
    backStack.addAll(s);
    return backStack;
}
```

This would seem to do all the work for me. Only problem is, I keep getting a nullPointerException when I run this in my main:

```
Stack s1 = new Stack();
s1.push("c");
s1.push("b");
s1.push("a");

DuplicateStack dup = new DuplicateStack();
Stack s2 = dup.duplicateStack(s1);

while(!s2.empty())
    System.out.println(s2.pop());
```

The error comes from the addAll() call in my DuplicateStack class.
So my question is why am I getting a nullPointerException from the addAll(), and is there any way to make a duplicate copy other than using the method stated earlier (using only Stack unique methods)?

Answer (score 2):

You get a `NullPointerException` because `backStack` is `null` (you never initialize it). Change

```
private Stack backStack;
```

to something like

```
private Stack backStack = new Stack();
```

Comment: Wow! I now feel a bit lame haha! Thanks :)